# Find all values of $x$ in the interval $[0,2\pi]$ that satisfy $\sin x + \tan x =1+ \sec x$

Tags: trigonometry

I've been doing some practice questions for a test, but I'm having issues with a a particular one.

Find all values of $x$ in the interval $[0,2\pi]$ that satisfy $$\sin x + \tan x =1+ \sec x$$

I wasn't sure what to do so I tried simplifying it, and I got it down to $$\sin x = 1$$

For which I would believe the answer is $\pi/2$ but the correct answer I'm told is just $\pi$. Have I messed up somewhere, or is the answer I was given incorrect?

Thanks

Comment: Well, plug $\frac {\pi}2$ back into the original and you'll see that neither side is well-defined.  Multiplying the original by $\cos(x)$ yields $\sin(x)(1+\cos(x))=1+\cos(x)\implies \cos(x)=-1\implies x=\pi$ (as, for the reason I mentioned, the solution $\sin(x)=1$, is not valid).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TLDR:** You forgot to account for the fact that, in dividing by $\cos x + 1$, you assume that it is non-zero.
$$\begin{align}
&\sin x + \frac{\sin x}{\cos x} =1+ \frac{1}{\cos x}\\
&\implies \sin x\cos x + \sin x = \cos x + 1\\
&\implies \sin x(\cos x + 1) = \cos x + 1\\
&\implies \sin x = 1 \quad \lor \quad \cos x  = -1\\
\end{align}$$
We now note that the first equality is solved when $x = \pi (n + \frac{1}{2})$ and the second is solved when $x = \pi(2n+1)$. However, we note that solutions to $\sin x = 1$ yield $+\infty$ on both the RHS and LHS of the original equation; Whether or not you define this as equality is somewhat contextual, as subtracting the RHS from the LHS to get $y =\sin x + \tan x - \sec x - 1$ yields zeroes at both $\frac \pi 2$ as well as at $\pi$. However, accepting only finite equality we can choose to ignore the solutions of the form $x = \pi (n + \frac{1}{2})$. Therefore, we only need to solve the RHS equality in the domain $[0,2\pi]$, with the only answer being $x= \pi$

**Note:** There is an interesting relationship between the RHS and LHS of your original equation at half multiplies of $\pi$, i.e. solutions to $\sin x = 1$. If we take the limit of the quotient of the RHS and LHS, i.e. $\lim_{x \to \pi}\frac{\sin x + \tan x}{1 + \sec x}$ we find that the answer is $1$, which means that, although both blow up to infinity at $\frac \pi 2$, they blow up at asymptotically the same rate.

Comment: Ahhh thank you so much, this question has been bothering me for the last couple hours.

Comment: @Ziamor No problem! Glad I could help :D

Comment: Actually, when you first multiply both sides by $cos(x)$ you shall impose that it is not null. Thus $sin(x)=1$ shall be discarded because of that, and remains only $cos(x)=-1$

Comment: @GCab True, but checking extraneous solutions seemed easier to explain to me :)

Comment: You cannot say that you discard $sinx=1$ because it gives $1+1/cosx=1+1/cosx$  *"which is clearly true for all $x$"* : pls. re-edit your answer.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen, let me solicit your action as per my comment above

Comment: @GCab oh yeah, forgot to make a note of this. I'll edit it now. You know, if you care so much you could edit it yourself XD

Comment: @GCab Alright, my most recent edit along with my Note at the bottom should cover it more fully. In essence, at points where $\sin x = 1$ the RHS and LHS both blow up to $+\infty$ at the same rate, and are thus, *in a sense*, equal, as seen by subtracting the RHS from the LHS. In the OP's case clearly only points where the functions are both finite and equal are allowed (which makes sense in most contexts), and so we can safely exclude these solutions

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen Ok, now I suppose it is *sustainable*. I don't know if I have credit enough to edit answers, yet I prefer the author to do it because, maths "cultures"  are different. I've been taught not to multiply by $0$ the sides of an equation. In this case however, at least as a limit, the two sides approach each other for $x$ -> $0$.

Comment: @GCab I understand :)  in my experience there is a time and place for multiplying  both sides of an equality by a function that is not everywhere zero. You just have to make sure that the function doesn't affect the points you need...  This can be checked by plugging solutions back into the original equality and seeing if it is ill defined. You *generally* don't lose solutions by multiplying,  so you're good there (you sometimes do,  but you just have to justify each step. I was lazy here and just graphed each step to check my work!).  More care is needed in dividing...  You lose solutions...

Comment: @GCab where the denominator is undefined. All in all I would say the advice of not multiplying both sides be zero is a good one, and it definitely solves the equation here more quickly. However,  I thought the behavior near $\frac \pi 2$ was too interesting to ignore due to its limiting equality.

Comment: @GCab TLDR: in essence,  don't multiply by function that can be zero and expect the equality to match at this points. In this case I already knew that $\frac \pi 2$ had interesting behavior so I went into detail on that instead,  because $\frac \pi 2$ does solve the equality in *some* contexts (differential equations come to mind immediately)

Comment: @GCab Wikipedia actually explains this on its Extraneous and Missing Solutions page... They give the example $x+2 = 2$. If we multiply by $x+2$ we find that $ (x+2)(x+2) = x^2 + 4x + 4 = 0$. This has $x= - 2$ as a solution,  and under the logic you give we must exclude it,  because we multiples by $x+2$ which gives zero at that point. In this case though the original equality is solved. This differs from the $\sin$ case in that a bijection does exist...  We can do the work to make sure we maintain a bijection throughout the process,  but checking for Extraneous Solutions at the end is *easier*

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen . The subject of *missing and extraneous solutions* is quite interesting, thanks indeed. Till now I was approaching the various cases in a less systematic way. It confirms  once again that MSE is a site where there is more to learn than to teach!